# Can low memory on IIS server cause SQL Timeouts (SQL Server on separate box)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, iis, ado.net

I have an IIS Web Server that hosts 400 web applications (distributed across 30 application pools). They are both ASP.NET applications and WCF Services end points. The server has 32GB of RAM and is usually running fast; although it's running at 95% memory usage. Worker processes each take between 500MB and 1.5GB of RAM.

I also have another box running SQL Server. That one has plenty of free memory.

Sometimes, the Web Server starts throwing *SQL Timeout exceptions*. A few per minutes at first and rapidly increasing to hundreds per minute; effectively making the server down. This problem affects applications in all pools. Some requests still complete but most of them don't. While this happens the CPU usage on the server is around 30% (which is the normal load on that box).

While this is happening, we can still use SQL Server Management Studio (from the IIS Server) to execute requests successfully (and fast).

The fix is to restart IIS. And then everything goes back to normal until the next time.

Because the server is running with very low memory, I feel like this is the cause. But I cannot explain the relationship between low memory and sudden bursts of SQL Timeout exceptions.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you insuring your sql connections are being closed and disposed in the code? Interesting scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory pressure can trigger **paging and garbage collection**. Both introduce latency which would not be present otherwise.

GC'ing 32GB of data can take seconds. Why would all app processes GC at the same time? Because at about 95% memory utilization Windows sets a "**low memory**" event that the CLR listens to. It will try to release memory to help other processes.

If the applications get into a paging frenzy that would also explain huge delays in normal execution.

This is just guessing, though. You can try **proving** it by looking at the "Hard page faults/sec" counter. There also must be a counter for "full GC" or "Gen 2 GC".

The **fix** would be running at a higher margin to the physical memory limit.

Comment: We are in the process of setting up a new server to split the load. Aftert that, I expect the two servers to run at 50% memory usage. If the errors stop occurring, I'll conclude that they were caused by memory pressure. If the errors continue to occur I'll have to keep searching for the root cause. I'll let you know.

Comment: We moved 40% of the applications to another server. The memory on the server where I had the issue is now around 80%. No unexpected SQL Timeout exceptions since then.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - even 2 month after the question was completed! The theory is proven now.

Comment: > The fix would be running at a higher margin to the physical memory limit. >           Is this a setting in IIS? SQL Server? OS? Please elaborate.

Comment: @jokab This is achieved by making the applications consume less memory, or by moving some to another server (this is what the OP did). There is no setting because a setting cannot forcefully reduce the amount of memory requested by applications.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

This property is the cumulative time-out for all network reads during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user processing time, only network read time.

It is a client based time out.  If stuff is getting queued due to memory constraints then that could cause a timeout.

Are you retrieving a lot of data from these queries?

If some queries return a lot of data consider breaking them up and give the user a next and prior button.

Have you considered asynch like BeginExecuteReader?
The advantage is no timeout.
It does not release the calling thread.

```
isExecutingFTSindexWordOnce = true;
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callbackFTSindexWordOnce, sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce);
// isExecutingFTSindexWordOnce set to false in the callback
Debug.WriteLine("Calling thread active");
```

But I agree with your comment how to respond to the request as the answer does not come back to the calling thread.
Sorry I am used to WPF where I just update a public property on the call back.

Comment: 1. Lot of data: some queries do and some queries don't. There are a lot of different applications involved. 2. How would BeginExecuteReader help? It would release the web request thread while the I/O is happening.

Comment: Really BeginExecuteReader would release the web request thread?  Did you test that?

Comment: BeginExecuteReader releases the calling thread while it's doing I/O. Getting a web service that calls BeginExecuteReader to release its calling thread (the web request) while it's waiting on BeginExecuteReader would require additional work. My point here was that I could not see how doing async I/O could help fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is to discover where the timeout is happening.  Can you tell from the stack trace if the timeout is happening when *executing* a request against the database, or when *connecting* to the database?  (Or even connecting to the *web server*?)

Timeouts executing database requests can be a variety of causes.  The problem might be in the database with blocking processes, database maintenance (also locking), deadlocks, etc.  When apps are running slowly, do you see a lot of entries in [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx), and if so, what are their wait_types?

Even if you can run SQL in the query window while the web server is timing out, that doesn't mean there isn't massive blocking or deadlocking going on.

If it is a timeout *connecting* to the database, then it is possible the ADO connection pools are overwhelmed and not getting cleaned up, or the database has a connection limit, and the web services are timing out waiting for a connection.

One of the best ways to find out what is going on is to capture a memory dump of the w3wp.exe process and analyze it.  Even if you aren't adept at a debugger like [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx), [Microsoft's DebugDiag tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798) can produce some nice reports with helpful information.